# Who is the killer in Still Life?

Tags: still-life

I just finished playing Still Life with a bunch of friends. In case you still want to play it, this question probably isn't for you.

> Still Life has quite a disappointing ending. None of us could tell who the murderer was at the end of the game. However, it looks like many clues are left behind and the creators actually intended to make the game longer. So, is it possible to find out who did it, or did the game just have an annoying open ending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microids has a nasty tendency to not finish a story in just one game... for example, Syberia and Syberia 2 are each half of a story.

From what I've read, the same thing happens in Still Life... the killer is revealed in its sequel, [Still Life 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Still_Life_2) (spoiler alert: The name of the killer is mentioned on that page).

Comment: Spoiler alert, that link contains the name of the killer :)

Comment: @agent86 Good point, I edited that into my answer.

Comment: Holy ****. I had no idea still life 2 was out. Time to go confirm if the killer is who I thought it was!!